# R: How to plot legend outside of plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am trying to plot legend and also simplify coding for plotting.

What I have right now is:

```
x <- c(1,4464)
y <- c(-60,10)

# Brianna 2012
     plot(BriannaJan[,3,1], xlim=range(x),ylim=range(y), type='l', ylab="Temperature", xlab="Time", main="Brianna 2013")
        par(new=T)
    plot(Briannafeb[,3,1], axes=F,col=11,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaMar[,3,1],axes=F,col=1,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaApr[,3,1],axes=F,col=2,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaMay[,3,1],axes=F,col=3,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaJun[,3,1],axes=F,col=4,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaJul[,3,1],axes=F,col=5,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaAug[,3,1],axes=F,col=6,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaSep[,3,1],axes=F,col=7,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaOct[,3,1],axes=F,col=8,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaNov[,3,1],axes=F,col=9,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))
        par(new=T)
    plot(BriannaDec[,3,1],axes=F,col=10,type="l",ylab="Temperature",xlab="Time", ylim=range(y))

    legend(4000,2.8,c(2013:1995), lty = 1, col=c(11,1:10))
```

I looked into some online materials, and I need to use `xpd=TRUE` to expand plot outside margin, but not sure where. Also, I tried `lines` instead of `plot`, but I could not plot well. For sure, if I can use `lines` instead, it would be simpler.

Please give me advice and suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of the `matplot` function?

Comment: You can use `layout` for this. E.g., see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10391001/1412059).

Answer (score 0):

if you do want to use `xpd = T` at some point you can do it inside `par()` which sets up the graphical parameters e.g.

```
    par(xpd = T)
    plot()
```