# Creating legend for multiple graphs in R

Tags: r

I wrote some code that reads some data from a text file, turns it into a matrix and plots each column of the matrix in a separate graph:

```
#Read data from txt file into table and convert table into matrix
excMatrix = as.matrix(read.table("/Users/Kane/Desktop/Gujarati/Table 1.3.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = 1))

#Plotting function
excPlot = function(x) {
  plot(row.names(excMatrix),x,xlab = "Year", ylab = "Exchange rate (US)", type = "l")
  legend("topright", legend = "something to get column names for legend", pch = 1, col = 1:2, bty = "n")
}

#Plot exchange rates from various countries on seperate graphs
apply(excMatrix, 2, excPlot)
```

When I run this it makes the correct graphs but I can't figure out how to get the name of the country in the legend i.e. each graph is data for a separate country who's names are the columns of the matrix.

Hopefully that makes sense, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some rearranging of your plotting method to loop over the `colnames` of your matrix will allow this to work. E.g.:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

excMatrix <- matrix(1:20,ncol=4,dimnames=list(1:5,letters[1:4]))

excPlot = function(x) {
  plot(row.names(excMatrix),excMatrix[,x],xlab = "Year", 
       ylab = "Exchange rate (US)", type = "l")
  legend("topright", 
         legend = x, 
         pch = 1, col = 1:2, bty = "n")
}

lapply(colnames(excMatrix), excPlot)
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually need all the plots on separate graphs that's why I set it up that way. But pretty sure I can still use this.

Comment: @Kane - no problems. I just had the `par()` line included in this example code so that you could see the labels being cycled through. Just remove it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using `par()` like what @thelatemail has pointed out. Do check out `?par`. It has many parameters such as margins and size for you to play with

If your legend is the same for each plot, you can place your `legend()` code outside of your `excPlot` function.

Take a look at this post on stackoverflow :

[Common legend for multiple plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389967/common-legend-for-multiple-plots-in-r)