# Overlapping histograms on one page in R

Tags: r, histogram

I am a beginner with R. I managed to plot my data into overlapping histograms. However, I would like to place all the histograms on one page. I am struggling as I am not able to tell R, which sets to pick (only manage to plot one of the plots).

This is the code:

```
        df<-read.csv("Salt dshalo sizes.csv",header=T)
    #View(df)

    library(ggplot2)

    DSA<-df[,1]
    DS1<-df[,2]
    DSB<-df[,5]
    DS2<-df[,6]
    DSC<-df[,9]
    DS3<-df[,10]

    #remove the NA column by columns separately or it will chop the data
    DSA=na.omit(DSA)
    DS1=na.omit(DS1)
    DSB=na.omit(DSB)
    DS2=na.omit(DS2)
    DSC=na.omit(DSC)
    DS3=na.omit(DS3)


    #plot histograms for DSA, DSB and DSC on one same graph 
    hist(DSA, prob=TRUE, main="Controls", xlab="Sizes (um)", ylab="Frequency", col="yellowgreen",xlim= c(5,25), ylim=c(0,0.5), breaks=10)
    hist(DSB, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),add=T)
    hist(DSC, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0.8,0,1,0.5),add=T)
    #add a legend to the histogram 
    legend("topright", c("Control 1", "Control2", "Control3"), text.width=c(1,1,1),lwd=c(2,2,2), 
           col=c(col="yellowgreen", col="blue", col="pink",cex= 1))
    box()

 #plot histograms for DS1, DS2 and DS3 on one same graph 
    hist(DS1, prob=TRUE, main="Monoculture Stressed", xlab="Sizes (um)", ylab="Frequency", col="yellowgreen",xlim= c(5,25), ylim=c(0,0.5), breaks=10)
    hist(DS2, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),add=T)
    hist(DS3, prob=TRUE, col=rgb(0.8,0,1,0.5),add=T)
    #add a legend to the histogram 
    legend("topright", c("DS1", "DS2", "DS3"), text.width=c(1,1,1),lwd=c(2,2,2), 
           col=c(col="yellowgreen", col="blue", col="pink",cex= 1))
    box()

# put both overlapping histograms onto one page
    combined <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
    plot(hist(DSA),main="Controls")
    plot(hist(DS1),main="Monoculture stressed")
    par(combined)
```

Basically, I get two separate overlapping histograms, but cannot put them on the same page.

Comment: If you are using base hist() as you appear to be doing, do a call to par(mfrow=c(a,b))   where a = number of rows of graphs, and b = number of columns of graphs.   Or do you mean to actually show the overlap on a single graph?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the par command. It does work, now I am having problems with the legends being squashed. Is there a way I can put a legend on the page?

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391001/4001897

Comment: Hi, that was the example I followed however I have problems with the legends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:  I evidently didn't read your question thoroughly. I see you figured out the add =T.

I assume what you are looking for then is the comment I made first:

`par(mfrow = c(a,b))` where a and b are the number of rows and columns you want the graphics objects to be printed.  I used c(2,2) for this pic.

[image]

I made a comment, but sounds like you may be talking about the add=T option.

```
a=rnorm(100, 2, 1)
b=rnorm(100, 4, 1)
hist(a, xlim=c(0,10), col="yellow")
hist(b, add=T, col="purple" )
```

you can play around with transparency options on colors to see both overlap. Such as rgb(1,0,0,1/4) as the color.

[image]

With transparency colors:

```
a=rnorm(100, 2, 1)
b=rnorm(100, 4, 1)
hist(a, xlim=c(0,10), col=rgb(1,1,0,1/4))
hist(b, add=T, col=rgb(1,0,0,1/4) )
```

[image]